# Committing hunks from inside of git add -i?

Tags: git, interactive

Is this possible? It would be nice if I didn't have to switch back and forth between git-add -i and git commit when breaking apart hunks into different commits. Is there a better way to do this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [git book](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_adding.html), a simple `git commit` is still required after a `git add --interactive` session.
(With the following caveat:

> Remember not to run '`git commit -a`', which will blow away all the careful changes you've just made and simply commit everything 
>   )

Note: maybe `git add -p` (`--patch`) will be a little more convenient:

> Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.
>
> This effectively runs `add --interactive`, but **bypasses the initial command menu and directly jumps to the patch subcommand**.

---

Bonus, with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), "`git add -i`" has been taught to show the total number of hunks and the hunks that has been processed so far when showing prompts.

See [commit 8085050](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8085050ab4e29f442f305e338e6eea750540190e) (30 Sep 2019) by [Kunal Tyagi (`kunaltyagi`)](https://github.com/kunaltyagi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f0d407e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0d407e6ae8dfe89683d86ebaba5f6f08959e8b3), 11 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `add -i`: show progress counter in the prompt

So, while you still need a separate commit step, at least you how far along you are during the completion of the interactive/patch `git add` session.